# How to test Push notification reachability on bulk set of android & iOS devices

Tags: mobile, push-notification

We have implemented push notification for iOS & Android phones. We have few accounts for each platform (as we have few applications). So far we have been able to test that on handful number of devices, thus handful number of notifications are getting correct but we need to be able to test our service with mass numbers. So can anyone is aware of some tool/services where we can create a virtual device and send reachability of the notification.